# Ionic 3: Can't get contacts photos

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, contacts

I use the [Ionic Contacts plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/contacts/) and I need to get the photos of my contact list. It works in iOS but not in Android.

I tried to sanitize, normalize URL, and all that I found on the internet but nothing worked.

Here's my code:

**home.ts**

```
userPhoto: any;
  getContacts() {
    this.contacts.find(['displayName', 'name', 'phoneNumbers', 'emails', 'photos'], {filter: "", multiple: true})
        .then(data => {
          console.table(data[0]);
          this.userName = data[0].displayName;
          this.userPhoto = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(data[0].photos[0].value);
        });
  }
```

**home.html**

```
<button ion-button (click)="getContacts()">Get contacts</button>

<p>Nom : {{ userName }}</p>

<hr />
<img [src]="userPhoto" style="width: 100px;">
```

The error that i got in Chrome inspector:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/1/photo
```

Do you have any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have the same error, there is a conflict with the webview plugin, when i remove it, it works.